# Update Function in Blender Addon

Tags: python, add-on

I'm writing a blender addon.

Is there a way to set/change a Property (e.g. BoolProperty) that is defined in bpy.types.Scene?

I would like a function, that is called each frame like a draw() method of a panel, but when I tyr to set the BoolProperty in the draw() method, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed
```

My specific situation: I have a List (CollectionProperty) and I want to ensure, that the name of the PointerProperty of the list item matches the name of the Item. In cases it does not (because object the PointerProperty is pointing to has been renamed), i want to change the name of the list item.

Thank you for your help!